# Problems setting the dimensions and position of a dialog with Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm having a couple problems setting the dimensions of a dialog with Prism.  I'm opening the dialog using Prism's `IDialogService.ShowDialog`

If I set the width and height to hard coded values (like the code below), the dialog opens at the correct size.

```xml
<UserControl 
    x:Class="MyProject.MyDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">            
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="800"/>-
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

</UserControl>
```

However, if I bind the width and height to properties of my view model, it seems like Prism uses the height that I bind, but doesn't bind the width.

For example, if I change my view to bind to the width and height, and then hard code the width and height to values in `OnDialogOpened`, the dialog looks like this (my resolution is  1920x1080 so the dialog is a lot more than 500 pixels wide).

```xml
<UserControl 
    x:Class="MyProject.MyDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">            
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>-
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

</UserControl>
```

```cs
public class MyDialogViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
{
    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;
    }
}
```

[image]

The second problem I have is that I have one monitor with 3440x1440 resolution and another with 1920x1020 resolution.  If I have the 3440x1440 resolution as my main display where my application runs and then I drag the application to the 1920x1080 display and open the dialog, the dialog opens so that the bottom portion of it is below the Windows taskbar.  Here is an example:

```xml
<UserControl 
    x:Class="MyProject.MyDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">        
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen" />    
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>-
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

</UserControl>
```

```cs
public class MyDialogViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
{
    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
        this.Height = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height * 2 / 3;
        this.Width = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height * 2 / 3;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Late, but if the problem persists: How are width and height be defined in the view model? I suspect there is a RaiseProperyChanged missing.